# Nominatim API does not return house number with CURL request but returns when requested via browser

Tags: php, laravel, openstreetmap, guzzle, nominatim

I am using OSM Nominatim API to reverse geocode address from lat lng. But i am facing this weird problem, when i hit api via CURL reuquest it does not return any house number.

```
function getAddressFromNominatim($lat,$lon){
$client = new Client();
$nominatimUrl = env('NOMINATIM_URL', 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?');
$nominatimUrl .= "lat={$lat}&lon={$lon}&format=json&accept-language=en";
$headers['json'] = [];
$headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0';

$request = $client->request('GET', $nominatimUrl,[
        'headers' => $headers
    ]);
$response = collect(json_decode((string) $request->getBody(), true));
if (!isset($response['display_name'])) {
    return 'Unable to geocode';
}
return $response['display_name'];

    }
```

**Response**

[image: Postman Response]

But when i hit the same url in browser, it returns house number

[image: Browser Response]

I am using Guzzle HTTP in Laravel 5.8 to make CURL requests.

Nominatim URL for Reference: [Click Here](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=43.213753025087726&lon=-88.00024470322579&format=json&accept-language=en)

Can anyone guide me with this ?

Comment: Testing with the input coordinate explained in the browser's inspect, gives you the same result?

Comment: Yes, i used all headers and body from browser's inspect, but it does not change anything.